# Why is my Ubuntu share seen as a printer in Windows 7?

Tags: samba

On Windows 7 the 'shares' on my Ubuntu 12.04 are coming up with a printer icon and Windows 7 then tries to install a printer. Why does this happen and what should I do to be able to use my share?

Answer (score 2):

Samba server by default, shows a *printers/print$* resources to anyone that browse the server shares. Samba actually doesn't know if cups, or other print server has actually a printer, but still show the shares. Actually, is quite weird that Windows 7 try to install this "printer" without asking you first, or without you asking Windows do so.

Since this is a Ubuntu site, I'll tell you how to resolve this from the Ubuntu/Samba perspective:

In your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, you will see entries like this:

```
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
```

What you have to do is, comment out or delete this lines. For commenting out just add a `#` or `;` at the start of the line. After modifying this line is recommendable to run `testparm` so you make sure that you didn't mess up.

Comment: Can this also be solved from within Nautilus or other GUI configuration tools for Samba?

Comment: @EliahKagan my experiences with GUI's managing services aren't the most pleasant. That said, I checked out my reverse dependencies on samba and samba4 and didn't found any suitable GUI to test, most of them were web based manager like gadmin and swat.